# How to disable the sort on a SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online

On my site I have a content editor, which displays the content of a SharePoint list. In my list I have 5 names. Which I want in a certain order. So I disable 
the sorting of the default view. But when I display my page it still gives
the names in alphabeticly order. How can I turn the sorting off.

P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show data with a certain order, we can create a "order" column in the list, then if you want to get data using REST API, we can use "$orderby=order" in REST API.